# Is there a means of using a Javascript function to tell if an anchor link has already been visited?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A web project I am building has a two-part front page. The first is the company logo and an "Enter" button. When the enter button is clicked, it triggers a JavaScript function that changes the display of the 'entry' page to hidden and reveals the rest of the index file.

However, when a user clicks the home page navigation button, it resets to the logo screen and enter button. Is there a means of using JavaScript to check the status of the "visited" css pseudoselector to avoid returning to the logo entry screen when user revisits that link?

Comment: For privacy/security reasons browsers will not let you figure that out.

Comment: Why not just store something in local storage when the button is clicked and read that when the page renders to determine whether to show your logo/enter page

Comment: Local storage or a cookie or track it with the session on your server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by using cookies, or by storing something on local storage that lets you know if the user has visited your site before.

Use local storage is pretty simple on javascript, you can take a look on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage